# json swift ios - sending parameters to a php-sql

Tags: php, ios, json, swift

Hello I am trying to send a couple of parameters from an SWIFT IOS application to a PHP-SQL database using JSON. Has tried several examples both sycronus and asyncronus but I do not get it to work.

Keep troubling with the converting of the JSON parameter string to a format that will be received on the other side.. (when i try in the browser it will work..but not from the app itself)

Here is the code - from PLAYGROUND 
(The response is API Response: OPTIONAL (Missing JSON)

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import CoreLocation
var str = "Hello, playground debug use of JSON and PHP"
import Foundation


let url = NSURL(string:"http://mywebserver-replaced.no/POSITION/update.php?")
let cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: cachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 2.0)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

// set Content-Type in HTTP header
let boundaryConstant = "----------V2ymHFg03esomerandomstuffhbqgZCaKO6jy";
let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundaryConstant
NSURLProtocol.setProperty(contentType, forKey: "Content-Type", inRequest: request)

// set data
var dataString = " "
dataString = "json={\"FBID\":10,\"Driving\":1,\"Latitude\":\"68.123\",\"Longitude\":\"22.124\",\"Time\":\"18:24\",\"Date\":\"07.10.2014\",\"Heading\":90}"
let requestBodyData = (dataString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData

println("\(requestBodyData)")  // This will print "Optional(<6a736f6e...and so on..
                               // And except the optional it is quite correct.. json={

request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

// set content length
// NSURLProtocol.setProperty(requestBodyData.length, forKey: "Content-Length", inRequest: request)

var response: NSURLResponse? = nil
var error: NSError? = nil
let reply = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&error)

let results = NSString(data:reply!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
println("API Response: \(results)")
```

What am i dooing wrong?

Comment: @Nica *Your edit is **not helpful***. Once you have sufficient reputation, you will be able to make minor fixes like these without cluttering up the suggested edits queue. However, until you reach that point, please avoid making edits that leave other parts of the post unfixed.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting wrong Content-Type

```
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

should be

```
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

And also

```
dataString = "json={\"FBID\":10,\"Driving\":1,\"Latitude\":\"68.123\",\"Longitude\":\"22.124\",\"Time\":\"18:24\",\"Date\":\"07.10.2014\",\"Heading\":90}"
```

Remove the json=, which makes the body not a valid json.

Comment: Hi Shuo - thanks for the answer. I tried with your "applicaiton/json" that is probably correct - but the code still do not work :-(.    The "response is still optional (Missing Json)